# Filtering a MVC dropdownlist eleminating default values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a project using MVC 5.0 and my code is like this .

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive, "Status", new { @class = "control-label col-md-3  col-md-offset-1" })
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

It is working fine but the problem is it is adding an extra value 'Not Set' along with the value 'true' and 'false'. How can I filter 'Not Set' value from the drop down list.

thanks
Utpal

Comment: You can't. You creating an `EditorFor()` method for a `nullable bool` that is the default implementation - If you do not want to allow `null` - change the property to `bool` and use `@Html.CheckboxFor(model.IsActive)`

Comment: Does your IsActive column can hold null values? this usually creates 'Not Set'

Comment: @Emil yes it is a nullable column as generated by entity framework. So what is the wayout for my problem.

Comment: @Utpal you can change your model to remove IsActive  accepting null

Comment: @Emil is there any other option because I donot have permission to change the model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    model => model.IsActive, 
    new SelectList(
        new[] 
        { 
            new { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" },
            new { Value = "false", Text = "No" },
        }, 
        "Value", 
        "Text",
        Model
    )
) %>
```

try this

try and set the default value for IsActive  in your action